# rs232 communication C# data read issue

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a problem regarding the rs232 communication with a Melfa rv-2aj robot. I am sending to commands in ASCII and when the robot replies via rs232 I get something like this:  ??QY?e0?L???0???0???. My first thought was that I am not doing a proper conversion from ASCII when I read from RS232, but if I convert this set of charaters to a unicode output I get some chinesse characters and this should not be right. As the robot sends a reply via rs232, makes me think that my implementation is not wrong , but maybe my approch has some faults in it. I think "?" represent ASCII characters that are not properly displayed.

Below I have attached the source code to my application.
Can somebody give some pointers on what I doing wrong when I am reading from the serial that i get his kind of ouput?
I would really appreciate any kind of help, suggestion or reference. 
Thank you very much.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text; 
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;


namespace RS232_Communication
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private SerialPort COM_port = new SerialPort();
    private byte[] _array = new byte[] {0};
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BAUDRate.Items.Add("2400");
        BAUDRate.Items.Add("4800");
        BAUDRate.Items.Add("9600");
        BAUDRate.Items.Add("14400");
        BAUDRate.Items.Add("19200");
        BAUDRate.Items.Add("28800");
        BAUDRate.SelectedIndex = 2;

        DATAUnit.Items.Add("5");
        DATAUnit.Items.Add("6");
        DATAUnit.Items.Add("7");
        DATAUnit.Items.Add("8");
        DATAUnit.Items.Add("9");
        DATAUnit.SelectedIndex = 3;

        ParityUnit.Items.Add("None");
        ParityUnit.Items.Add("Odd");
        ParityUnit.Items.Add("Even");
        ParityUnit.Items.Add("Mark");
        ParityUnit.Items.Add("Space");
        ParityUnit.SelectedIndex = 2;

        STOPUnit.Items.Add("One");
        STOPUnit.Items.Add("Two");
        STOPUnit.SelectedIndex = 1;

        this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
        SendText.KeyPress +=new KeyPressEventHandler(SendText_KeyPress);
        COM_port.DataReceived +=new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(COM_port_DataReceived);
    }

    private string GetString(byte[] bBuffer, int iIndex, int iLen, bool bUni)
    {
        string sBuffer;
        if (bUni) sBuffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bBuffer, iIndex, iLen);
        else sBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bBuffer, iIndex, iLen);
        //return the string
        return sBuffer;
    }

     void COM_port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReceiveText.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
            {
                byte[] data = new Byte[COM_port.BytesToRead];
                COM_port.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                //string read = GetString(data, 0, data.Length, true);
                 string read = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);



                ReceiveText.AppendText(read);

                //ReceiveText.AppendText(COM_port.ReadExisting());
            }
         )
         )
         ;

    }

    void Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string COMstr in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
            COMPort.Items.Add(COMstr);

        if (COMPort.Items.Count > 0)
            COMPort.SelectedIndex = 0;
        else MessageBox.Show("No COM Ports available");

    }

    private void ConnectBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (COM_port.IsOpen)
            {
                COMPort.Enabled = true;
                BAUDRate.Enabled = true;
                ParityUnit.Enabled = true;
                STOPUnit.Enabled = true;
                DATAUnit.Enabled = true;
                COM_port.DtrEnable = false;
                COM_port.RtsEnable = false;
                ConnectBTN.Text = "Connect";
                COM_port.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                COM_port.BaudRate = int.Parse(BAUDRate.Text);
                COM_port.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), ParityUnit.Text);
                COM_port.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), STOPUnit.Text);
                COM_port.DataBits = int.Parse(DATAUnit.Text);
                COM_port.PortName = COMPort.Text;
               //COM_port.DtrEnable = true;
                //COM_port.RtsEnable = true;

                COM_port.Open();
                COM_port.ReadTimeout = 2000;
                COM_port.WriteTimeout = 2000;
                COMPort.Enabled = false;
                BAUDRate.Enabled = false;
                ParityUnit.Enabled = false;
                STOPUnit.Enabled = false;
                DATAUnit.Enabled = false;
                ConnectBTN.Text = "Disconnect";
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Error");
        }
    }

    public void WriteBytes(byte[] array)
    {
        COM_port.Write(array, 0, array.Length);

    }

    public void WriteBytes(byte[] array, int index, int length)
    {
        COM_port.Write(array, index, length);
    }


    public void WriteLine(String line)
    {
        //string s="";
        //foreach (byte b in StringToBytes(line + "\r\n"))
        //    s = s + b.ToString();
        //COM_port.WriteLine(s);
        WriteBytes(StringToBytes(line + "\r\n"));//CR + LF

    }

    public static byte[] StringToBytes(string input)
    {
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
    }

    private void SendBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SendText.Text != "")
         {
            WriteLine(SendText.Text);
            //COM_port.WriteLine(SendText.Text);
            SendText.Text = "";
        }

    }

    void SendText_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
        {
            WriteLine(SendText.Text);
            //COM_port.WriteLine(SendText.Text);
            SendText.Text = "";
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: MY QUESTION MY BE HELP TO UNDERSTAND MORE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289294/c-sharp-readbyte-function-for-lsb-first-7-bit-even-1-stop-bit-cas-mwp-3000h-rs

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out what was the problem. In the manual for the rv-2aj it is specified that in order to use the rs232 communication the following parameters have to be set: baud rate 9600, parity even, stop bits 2, data bits 8. So I configured my communication this way, and when I sent data to the controller I would receive strange messages as I showed in my previous post. It seems that the configuration for communication on the robot side was different then mine, so I changed the value for parity to none and the stop bits to one and now everything works as expected. I get proper feedback from the robot and the commands work. The code I wrote in c# works fine, no necessary modifications required.